# Does the ordered pair $(\{A,B\},C)$ contain the pairs $(A,C)$ and $(B,C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to this whole notion about the ordered pair, and I am a bit confused by the oredered-pair notation $(\{A,B\},C)$ that can be produced from performing the Cartesian product of sets. Does the pair $(\{A,B\},C)$ contain the pairs $(A,C)$ and $(B,C)$ (i.e. does the notation $(\{A,B\},C)$ mean that the pair can be either $(A,C)$ or $(B,C)$)? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a pair of concepts the first of which is a set and the other is a number (or whatever the capital letters represents). Not anything more to it unless specifically told otherwise. You can have pairs of a lot of things, just some examples:
$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ pair of numbers
$(A,\cdot)$ a set and an operation, and etc.

Comment: So to sum up, the pairs $(\{A,B\},C)$, $(A,C)$, and $(B,C)$ are just three distinct pairs with no relationship whatsoever among them (except that the $A$ and $B$ are the elements of the set $\{A,B\}$, which is the first element of the first pair)? something makes me to interpret $(\{A,B\},C)$ as the notation that indicates a given pair that can either be $(A,C)$ or $(B,C)$... (i.e. $(\{A or B\}, C)$)

Comment: (A,C) and (B,C) are the same 'type' of pair, but yeah, no relation whatsoever in principle.

Comment: $\{A,B\}$ is a set so there's no first or second element in that one.
It makes some sense to think about the "or" idea but you see that represented as $\{(A,C),(B,C)\}$. 
There are ways in which the specific $(Set,Element)$ is a natural way to think about something, the first example that popped in my head is Family/Person relationships, Points and Lines between them and stuff like that are generally represented like that.